# Are there some methods in golang manipulate function like std::bind in C++?

Tags: c++, go

Here is my design:

```
type Handler func(c *gin.Context)
func PreExecute(c *gin.Context, handle_func Handler) Handler {
    if c.User.IsAuthorized {
        return handle_func
    } else {
        return some_error_handle_func
    }
}
```

and I want to decorate every handler by PreExecute just like the decoration in Python. So I am looking for some std::bind functions in golang to get PreExecute a exactly same signature as Handler

What I expect:

```
handler = std::bind(PreExecute, _1, handler) // where _1 hold the position for parameter `c *gin.Context`
```

some function like std::bind

How can I do that in Golang? Are there some more elegant methods to get this work?

Comment: Please don't spam the tags. Only use tags which are related to your question.

Comment: @ChristianDean actually I am enlightened by the python of concept of the aop, or decoration, so I think it's not spam tag. perhaps someone else may 
 be interested in this question

Answer (score 2):

Closure, here is my solution:

```
handler_new = func(c *gin.Context){ return PreExecute(c, handler_old)(c) } // since there is no return value of handler, so just do not use `return` statements, I will not correct this error
```

and then handler_new can be used as:

```
handler_new(some_context)
```

It's the same as

```
handler_new = std::bind(PreExecute, _1, handler_old)
```

in C++